# No data in GA with GTM for Android..?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase

Could someone help me out..?

There is no data being captured in GA. I use GTM for Android (latest versions) and I have already done the following things:

- Set up the Google Play services SDK and added permissions to the Android manifest file.
- Added a default GTM container to the project (binary).
- Initialized GTM by the latest support pages of Google.
- Pushed events and valus to the dataLayer.
- I have set up GTM with the right tags, triggers and variable names and configuration.

This is most of the code that is used so far:

#### Splash activity

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long TIMEOUT_FOR_CONTAINER_OPEN_MILLISECONDS = 2000;
    private static final String CONTAINER_ID = "GTM-XXXXXX";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);

        if (Environment.get() != BaseEnvironment.PRODUCTION) {
            tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);
        }

        PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending = tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(CONTAINER_ID, R.raw.gtm_xxxxxx);

        pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
                ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);

                if (! containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    return;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, NavigationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }, TIMEOUT_FOR_CONTAINER_OPEN_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

#### Info activity

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    TagUtils.pushOpenScreenEvent(this, "Informatie");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    TagUtils.pushCloseScreenEvent(this, "Informatie");
}
```

#### TagUtils

```
/**
 * Push an "openScreen" event with the given screen name. Tags that match that event will fire.
 */
public static void pushOpenScreenEvent(Context context, String screenName) {
    DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();
    dataLayer.pushEvent("openScreen", DataLayer.mapOf(
            "screenName", screenName,
            "appVersion", appVersionName(context),
            "operatingSystem", systemVersion()
    ));
}

/**
 * Push a "closeScreen" event with the given screen name. Tags that match that event will fire.
 */
public static void pushCloseScreenEvent(Context context, String screenName) {
    DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();
    dataLayer.pushEvent("closeScreen", DataLayer.mapOf(
            "screenName", screenName,
            "appVersion", appVersionName(context),
            "operatingSystem", systemVersion()
    ));
}

/**
 * Push a "scanProduct" event with the given screen name. Tags that match that event will fire.
 */
public static final String ACTION_PRODUCT_FOUND = "Product gevonden";
public static final String ACTION_PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND = "Product niet gevonden";
public static final String ACTION_PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND_CONNECTION_ISSUES = "Product niet opgehaald door verbindingsproblemen";

public static void pushScanProductEvent(Context context, String action, String code) {
    DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();
    dataLayer.pushEvent("scanProduct", DataLayer.mapOf(
            "Category", "Scan",
            "Action", action,
            "Label", code
    ));
}
```

#### Manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.PreviewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="tagmanager.c.nl.everybodylikespenguins" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Please note I have hidden the container file ID and the *data android:scheme="tagmanager.c.nl.everybodylikespenguins"* is indeed the right name of the acceptation build of the app (Google also uses this in their example).

Comment: Have you published the Container?

Comment: Hi J Brazier, Yes, I've published the container, the published container is in version 7 right now. Any other suggestions perhaps? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't; my own experience relates entirely to web application of GTM. You mentioned that you've set up GTM with the right tags, triggers and variables, so there is no more common ground.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway. I have most experience with the web application of GTM as well. That is why I know that GTM is configured fine right now. However, I hoped someone could look for a fault in the code or has a suggestion that could lead to a possible solution.

Comment: Any other suggestions..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not calling containerHolder.getContainer() in the onResult callback. A call to getContainer is necessary to activate the container.